# UICollectionView cells covering up the scroll indicator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

The sections in my UICollectionView have 0 insets on the right, making my cells flush with the right sides of the collection view. The scroll view indicator is being covered by the cells. Is there a way to make the scroll view indicator always on top?

Comment: What about changing the scroll view indicator color? `scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;`

Comment: The indicator is being covered, it is not a problem of color. It is visible when the scroll view is over-scrolled and the indicator can be seen below or above the cells. But the cells cover the scroll indicator.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your view and hierarchy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the collection view flow layout I was using to get sticky headers for my collection views. I was using CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout (https://github.com/jamztang/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout), which was also causing another problem of touches passing through my headers (which had segmented controls in them for changing the sorting). I would advise NOT to use this flow layout.

A better, working collection view flow layout for sticky headers is https://stackoverflow.com/a/15689942/2142100. This fixed both of my problems.