# UICollectionView Header section Issue

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` contains `cell` and `header`. I have 4 sections each section has 3 or 5 cell. My issue is the section header won’t stick until I get to the next section header as in the `TableView`. Please where would be my issue?

My code:

```
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 4
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView
{

    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "headersection", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MenuHeaderCollectionViewCell

    header.headerTitle.text = collectionheader[indexPath.row]

    return header
}
```

[image] [image]

Comment: Can you add image? What do you mean by doesn't stick?

Comment: Ok I will add screenshot in minutes. What I mean is the header wont stop at the top it scroll with the cells.

Comment: @MayurDeshmukh I've add two image which shows the header section before and after scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to choose the proper `FlowLayout`. You will get what you need [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233180/uicollectionview-with-a-sticky-header)

Also check [CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout](https://github.com/jamztang/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout)

Comment: So you are telling me there is no way like in the `TablevView` without framework?