# iOS - Sticky headers with content inset - Header view is not scrolling like the cell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewflowlayout

We tried to roll the `UICollectionView` like a list over the map. This is not to be confused with bottom sheet which snaps to a point (like low, mid and high). The collectionview's flowlayout property has `sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds` enabled. I have attached the sample project for your reference. Is there any way the header view can move to the top of the collectionview as the user scrolls?

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17-oWrUcF2-AnsabXdM--tnqGZC9op4aV/view?usp=sharing) is the sample project

Essential changes need for me to enter that state:

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0

let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero,
                                              collectionViewLayout: layout)


override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
  super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

  collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: drawerHeight, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}
```

Here is a screenshot of what you would see: 
[image]

Red colored view is the header view which is pinned. Do I need a custom layout to update its position as the user scrolls?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a custom StickyHeaderLayout inspired from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49300238/1084075). Here is the fix to my bug:

```
class StickyHeaderLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        configureLayout()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configureLayout()
    }

    private func configureLayout() {
        self.sectionFootersPinToVisibleBounds = true
        self.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
        minimumLineSpacing = 0
        minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        guard let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect) else { return nil }

        for attribute in attributes {
            adjustAttributesIfNeeded(attribute)
        }
        return attributes
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        guard let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind: elementKind, at: indexPath) else { return nil }
        adjustAttributesIfNeeded(attributes)
        return attributes
    }

    func adjustAttributesIfNeeded(_ attributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
        switch attributes.representedElementKind {
        case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader?:
            adjustHeaderAttributesIfNeeded(attributes)
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    private func adjustHeaderAttributesIfNeeded(_ attributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return }
        guard attributes.indexPath.section == 0 else { return }

        if collectionView.contentOffset.y <= 0 {
            attributes.frame.origin.y = 0
        } else {
            attributes.frame.origin.y = collectionView.contentOffset.y
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one section is work， but if you have great than one section， it will cause some prolems